# Using .htaccess to rewrite a file with extension

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create an htaccess rule that will allow a URL like this:

```
example.com/some/random/file.mp3
```

To point to:

```
example.com?track.php?file=some/random/file.mp3
```

So I have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /track.php?file=$1 [QSA]
```

...and for those of you who know what you're doing, you will know quite quickly that this is not working.

Could someone help me get this rule written correctly?

Comment: The rule is working fine for me. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: What error are you getting when you visit `example.com/some/random/file.mp3` in browser?